# Авто-декремент mysql+php(автоматически)?

Tags: php, mysql, время

собственно, тут такой вопрос
Есть игра(обычная текстовая html,css,php +mysql)

Есть ссылка(посадить растение) при нажатии на неё в базу mysql должен заноситься временной интервал(40 минут) и каждую секунду или минуту уменьшаться вплоть до окончания этих 40 минут(попутно нужно выводить это значение из бд для информирования юзера)

Какие форматы использовать? сделать поле int которое принимает 40*60?
Или datetime,timestamp?

Какими средствами это можно реализовать? Без критической нагрузки на базу
PS гуглил инфу, нашел mysql event,но проблема в том, что если у меня будет 5тыс юзеров - нагрузка на бд просто гигантская
Заранее спасибо огромное

Comment: 5000 юзеров. Вы должно быть оптимист.

Answer (score 0):

Используй redis, там есть такой функционал из коробки. Либо считай дельту только при необходимости. Если по истечении срока надо удалять запись, можно по крону запускать каждую минуту скрипт на удаление с условием на разность текущей и даты посадки твоего растения. Имхо, редис самое бодрое решение для подобных задач.

Comment: А не будет такой штуки что при заполнении памяти отведенной редису до предела старые записи будут выталкиваться бесследно?

Comment: Если закончится память, однозначно ни чего хорошего не будет. Надо расчитывать, в общем то как и при покупке любого хостинга.